# Python sympy - simplify nonzero factors from an equation

Tags: python, sympy, reduce, simplify

I am using the sympy library for python3, and I am handling equations, such as the following one:

```
a, b = symbols('a b', positive = True)
my_equation = Eq((2 * a + b) * (a - b) / 2, 0)
```

`my_equations` gets printed exactly as I have defined it (`(2 * a + b) * (a - b) / 2 == 0`, that is), and I am unable to reduce it even using `simplify` or similar functions.

What I am trying to achieve is simplifying the nonzero factors from the equation (`2 * a + b` and `1 / 2`); ideally, I'd want to be able to simplify `a - b` as well, if I am sure that `a != b`.

Is there any way I can reach this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that *simplify()* is not capable (yet) of complex reasoning about assumptions. I tested it on Wolfram Mathematica's simplify, and it works. It looks like it's a missing feature in SymPy.

Anyway, I propose a function to do what you're looking for.

Define this function:

```
def simplify_eq_with_assumptions(eq):
    assert eq.rhs == 0  # assert that right-hand side is zero
    assert type(eq.lhs) == Mul  # assert that left-hand side is a multipl.
    newargs = []  # define a list of new multiplication factors.
    for arg in eq.lhs.args:
        if arg.is_positive:
            continue  # arg is positive, let's skip it.
        newargs.append(arg)
    # rebuild the equality with the new arguments:
    return Eq(eq.lhs.func(*newargs), 0)
```

Now you can call:

```
In [5]: simplify_eq_with_assumptions(my_equation)
Out[5]: a - b = 0
```

You can easily adapt this function to your needs. Hopefully, in some future version of SymPy it will be sufficient to call *simplify*.

Comment: I think this feature is currently missing because it would make simplify( ) too slow in most cases. Maybe it will be added when the code handling assumptions has been rewritten in C++.

Comment: Thank you, I finally ended up doing something like that.